# Rails 5 Asset Naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Why does my main scss file need to be called 'application.scss'? Why can it not be named 'foo.scss' and be included in application.html.erb?

manifest.js

```
// JS and CSS bundles
//
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css


// Images and fonts so that views can link to them
//
//= link_tree ../fonts
//= link_tree ../images
```

Css import

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'foo', media: 'all' %>
```

Error when i use 'foo.scss'

> Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
>   Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( foo.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

If i use the file name 'application.scss' it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails precompiles the assets. The default matcher for compiling files includes `application.js`, `application.css` and all non-JS/CSS files (this will include all image assets automatically) from `app/assets` folders including your gems:

```
[ Proc.new { |filename, path| path =~ /app\/assets/ && !%w(.js .css).include?(File.extname(filename)) }, /application.(css|js)$/ ]
```

If you have other `manifests` or individual `stylesheets` and `JavaScript` files to include, you can add them to the precompile array in `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( foo.js foo.css )
```

So this tells rails to precompile your `manifest` file in production mode. And this is what your error says to add that in `assets.rb` and restart the server.